# transaction in php like mysql transaction

Tags: php, transactions

I want to have something like database transaction but in my `PHP`  code

my problem is :

-add n number data to database

-add to some file

I want to cancel whole process if one of them failed.
 some one Offered me to use `PDO`, but it is not what I want .
any help?

Comment: Have you looked into [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)?

Comment: its not possible every where, but if you want it just for your project,edit your question and copy some code there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very nice and useful question , but it is impossible to do.

if you want to do the transaction in `mysql` , its easy and  its obvious that you know it yourself.

but
consider that:

how can `php` reverse your request to a web service, or a socket , or email , or ...

its not possible to do such thing in `php` , even with `PDO` library. `PDO` is for `php-mysql` transaction